# Coinduction principle for smash products of pointed cpos

Tags: pl.programming-languages, domain-theory

In ["Relational Properties of Domains"](https://doi.org/10.1006/inco.1996.0052), Pitts gives a coinduction principle for pointed cpos (cppos). In corollary 6.13 (below), he specializes it to cppos constructed as fixed points of cppo-constructors $\Phi$. A cppo-constructor is a syntactic expression $\Phi$ constructed from a single variable $\alpha$, constant cppos $K$, and lifting $({-})_\bot$, products $\times$, smash products $\otimes$, coalesced sums $\oplus$, etc. Given a $\Phi$ and a cppo $D$, replacing every occurence of $\alpha$ determines a cppo $\Phi(D)$.

To state the coinduction principle, Pitts defines the action of $\Phi$ on binary relations. Given a cppo $D$ and a relation $R \subseteq D \times D$, the relation $\Phi(R) \subseteq \Phi(D) \times \Phi(D)$ is inductively defined on the structure of $\Phi$. The following corollary then gives a coinduction principle (reminiscent of simulations in process calculi) for the recursively defined cppo $D \cong \Phi(D)$:

> Corollary 6.13: Let $\Phi(\alpha)$ be a cppo-constructor built up from the variable $\alpha$ and constants $K$ ranging over cppos, using $({-})_\bot$, $\times$, $\otimes$, $\oplus$, $\to$, and $\multimap$. Let $D = \mathit{rec}\ \alpha.\Phi(\alpha)$ be the cppo recursively defined by $\alpha = \Phi(\alpha)$, with associated isomorphism $i : \Phi(D) \cong D$. Then for any $d, d' \in D$, to prove $d \sqsubseteq d'$ it suffices to show $(d, d') \in R$ for some subset $R \subseteq D \times D$ satisfying: $$ \forall (x, x') \in R . (i^{-1}(x), i^{-1}(x')) \in \Phi(R). $$

Let's say that $R$ is a simulation for $D$ if it satisfies the hypotheses of the statement.

My question involves the definition of $\Phi(R)$, which I think has a bug.
The construction of $\Phi(R)$ from $R$ seems reasonable in most cases.
For example, $\Phi_\bot(R)$ relates elements $d$ and $d'$ if $d$ and $d'$ are both $\bot$ or if they are both the lift of elements related by $\Phi(R)$.
Similarly, constants $K$ relate elements using $\sqsubseteq_K$:
$$
\begin{align}
(d, d') \in \Phi_\bot(R) &\Leftrightarrow d \neq \bot \implies (d' \neq \bot \land (d, d') \in \Phi(R)),\\
(d, d') \in K(R) &\Leftrightarrow d \sqsubseteq_K d'.
\end{align}
$$
The definition for products is also reasonable: $(\Phi_1 \times \Phi_2)(R)$ relates tuples component-wise:
$$((d, e), (d', e')) \in (\Phi_1 \times \Phi_2)(R) \Leftrightarrow (d,d') \in \Phi_1(R) \land (e, e') \in \Phi_2(R).$$
In contrast, the definition of $(\Phi_1 \otimes \Phi_2)(R)$ for smash products is surprising. In the paper and [technical report](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Eamp12/papers/relpod/relpod.pdf), it is stated as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
(u,u') &\in (\Phi_1 \otimes \Phi_2)(R)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall d \in (\Phi_1(D))_\downarrow, e \in (\Phi_2(E))_\downarrow (u=(d,e)\\
&\Rightarrow \exists d' \in (\Phi_1(D))_\downarrow, e' \in (\Phi_2(E))_\downarrow (d,d') \in \Phi_1(R)\\
&\land (e, e') \in \Phi_2(R))
\end{align}
$$
where $D_\downarrow = \{ d \in D \mid d \neq \bot \}$.
I expect that all occurrences of $E$ in the definition of $(\Phi_1 \otimes \Phi_2)(R)$ are typos and that they should be $D$. What I find surprising, however, is that $u'$ appears nowhere on the right side of the definition.

As given, this implies that $A \otimes B = \{ (\bot, \bot) \}$ for all cppos $A$ and $B$. To see why, consider $\Phi(\alpha) = A \otimes B$. Then $i = \mathsf{id} : \Phi(A \otimes B) \cong A \otimes B$ is the canonical fixed point (minimal invariant in the terminology of Pitts/Freyd). Consider the relation $R = \{((a,b), (\bot, \bot)) \mid (a, b) \in A \otimes B \}$. The relation $R$ is easily seen to be a simulation. To see why, we compute $(A \otimes B)(R)$:
$$
\begin{align}
(u,u') &\in (A \otimes B)(R)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall d \in A_\downarrow, e \in B_\downarrow (u=(d,e)\\
&\Rightarrow \exists d' \in A_\downarrow, e' \in B_\downarrow (d \sqsubseteq_A d'\\
&\land e \sqsubseteq_B e')).
\end{align}
$$
Given $((a, b), (\bot, \bot)) \in R$, we have $((a, b), (\bot, \bot)) \in (A \otimes B)(R)$ (take $d'= a$ and $e' = b$).
The corollary then implies that $(a, b) \sqsubseteq_{A \otimes B} (\bot, \bot)$ for all $(a, b) \in A \otimes B$, i.e., that every element of $A \otimes B$ is equal to $(\bot, \bot)$.

What I would have expected is:
$$
\begin{align}
(u,u') &\in (\Phi_1 \otimes \Phi_2)(R)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \forall d \in (\Phi_1(D))_\downarrow, e \in (\Phi_2(D))_\downarrow (u=(d,e)\\
&\Rightarrow \exists d' \in (\Phi_1(D))_\downarrow, e' \in (\Phi_2(D))_\downarrow (u' = (d', e')\\
&\land (d,d') \in \Phi_1(R) \land (e, e') \in \Phi_2(R))).
\end{align}
$$
Is this revision correct? Or have I missed some crucial detail somewhere?